# Facebook integration always login from the Facebook app not in separate Dialog in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've integrated Facebook in Android app. If i don't have Facebook app in my device then its asking a popup for login and working fine.

If i already installed Facebook app in my device, then i click Facebook login from my app then its taking the already signed in Facebook account.

I've tested with many examples, all are taking from the installed app if available.

So, How to login always with separate account without respective Facebook app. Is it possible or not? Please suggest with any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the active facebook session in onCreate() of Activity. so that when user clicks on login button it asks for new session and does not take the active session. You can clear the session by

```html
closeAndClearTokenInformation()
```

method of Session.

```html
public static void fbClearToken(Context context) {
  Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
  if (session != null) {

   if (!session.isClosed()) {
    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    // clear your preferences if saved
   }
  } else {
   session = new Session(context);
   Session.setActiveSession(session);
   session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
   // clear your preferences if saved
  }
 }
```

Comment: will this code sign out the already login user in Facebook app?

Comment: Yes. It will clear the current sessio. As session will not be available. it will ask for login.